# How to purge okular?

Tags: okular, removing

I have ubuntu 20.10, 64 bit.
In Menu, there are 2 instances of Okular.
I can use it but cannot remove via Terminal.

```
igor@igor-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt remove okular
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'okular' is not installed, so not removed
```

In the Software center, Okular is not marked as installed.

Please advise.

Comment: Please add output of `which okular` to the question.

Comment: Hard to say. Menu states "Okular", no more. And when I open a book using Okular, the latter doesn't name itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be installed from one of three sources - [APT](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=okular), [Snap](https://snapcraft.io/okular), [FlatPak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.kde.okular).

To remove it completely use:

```
sudo apt-get remove okular
snap remove okular
flatpak remove flathub org.kde.okular
```

Comment: Done. And I got the same answer from Terminal.

Comment: Okular removed on the second attempt (snap remove okular). Thank you.